# Show elements based on form input

Tags: jquery, html

Check out the following simplified code:

```
<select id="number">
  <option value="">Select...</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>

<div id="show1" style="display:none;">Section 1</div>
<div id="show2" style="display:none;">Section 2</div>
<div id="show3" style="display:none;">Section 3</div>
<div id="show4" style="display:none;">Section 4</div>
<div id="show5" style="display:none;">Section 5</div>
```

What I want to achieve is this: if the user selects the option "2" in the drop down, I want to show (make visible) the first two divs. If the user selects "4", I want thhe first four divs visible, and so on and so forth.

What is the best way of writing a jQuery function such that it is very short, efficient and scalable (the function remains unchanged even if I scale it up from 5 to 30 options)?

Answer (score 3):

```
var $sections = $('.section');
$('#number').change(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    $sections.hide(1, function(){
        $sections
            .slice(0, value)
            .show();    
    });
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/ZjPdw/)

Comment: An interesting variation. Very tight. Thanks.

Comment: @RCH: I changed to code to cache the `$sections` object, so you will not have an overhead of constructing it every time a change event fires.

Comment: @Tomalak: You have a peculiar way of expressing your knowledge. I am sure something is cooking in your mind, but you just don't want to share it that easy. :)

Comment: @Shef: All I said was, I don't like the flicker.

Comment: @Tomalak: Yeah, and all I said was, I have noticed when you don't like something, there is a solution cooking in your mind. :) I have updated the code, I hope you will like the less flicker.

Comment: @Shef: Nah, no solution in my mind today. Just thought I'd comment :)

Comment: You could also do `slice(0, value)` instead of `filter()`.

Comment: @Tomalak: Yeah, and obviously that [would be much faster](http://jsperf.com/jquery-filter-sizzle-vs-slice).

Comment: @Shef: Hm, that was unexpected. No need for sarcasm, though.

Comment: @Tomalak: What was unexpected the result or the test altogether?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$("#number").bind("change", function () {
    var value = parseInt(this.value, 10);

    $("div[id^='show']").hide();

    for(var i = 1; i <= value; i++) {
        $("#show" + i).show();
    }
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/cVjtv/

**Notes:**

- [`bind`](http://api.jquery.com/bind)s an event handler to the [`change`](http://api.jquery.com/change) event of the `select#number` element.
- Uses [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide) and the [attribute starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) to hide all `div`s beginning with "show"
- Loops from 1 to *n* inclusively, where *n* is the value selected in the `select` element, hiding the appropriate `div` in each iteration.

**Update:** Here's a more concise (but less readable) version, kind of like @Shef's:

```
$("#number").bind("change", function () {
    var value = parseInt(this.value, 10);

    $("div[id^='show']")
        .hide()
        .filter(function () {
            var id = parseInt(this.id.replace("show", ""), 10);
            return id <= value;
        })
        .show();
});
```

Comment: That works a treat - thanks very much. Was looking for something just like this.

Comment: @Tomalak: Right you are, me neither

Comment: Although I have a hunch that the way `.show` works on matched elements might be the culprit (and perhaps beyond my control)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#number').change(function(){
    // get the value of the selected list item
    var v = parseInt($(this).val()) + 1
    // hide all divs, then filter for divs with id less than the slected list item
    $('div').css({display:'none'}).filter(function(){
        return parseInt($(this).attr('id').replace(/show/,'')) < v
    // display the filtered divs
    }).css({display:'block'})
})
```

demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/Gyx9D/

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd remove the id's from the divs (maybe apply a class if you want the selector to be a little more specific) and wrap them in a parent (let's call it target). From there you can display only the first n child divs using a simple function. So the structure is:

```
<select id="number">
 <option value="">Select...</option>
 <option value="1">1</option>
 <option value="2">2</option>
 <option value="3">3</option>
 <option value="4">4</option>
 <option value="5">5</option> 
</select>

<div id="target">
 <div style="display:none;">Section 1</div>
 <div style="display:none;">Section 2</div>
 <div style="display:none;">Section 3</div>
 <div style="display:none;">Section 4</div>
 <div style="display:none;">Section 5</div>
</div>
```

You can use the following to bind the change of the select and hide / show the divs :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#number').live('change', function() {

  var count = $(this).val();

  $('#target div').each(function(i, n){

   if(i < count)
   {
    $(n).show();
   }
   else
   {
    $(n).hide();
   }
  });
 });
});
```